# Figure with caption but without label in tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter, tikzfigure

I'm making a poster in tikzposter, and I would like to have a figure with caption, but without label (i.e, I don't want the caption to start with "Figure 1: ...").

I'm using tikzfigure like so:

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[Caption goes here]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.08\textwidth]{image.png}
\end{tikzfigure}
```

which works except that the caption includes the label. Is there a way to remove the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tikzfigure` environment is defined as:

```
\newenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
  \begin{center}
  }{
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else %nothing
    \\[10pt]
    {\small Fig.~\thefigurecounter: \rememberparameter}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
```

Therefor you could try to place something like the following code in you preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
  \begin{center}
  }{
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else %nothing
    \\[10pt]
    {\small \rememberparameter}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That worked, I just had to change ```\newenvironment```  to ```\renewenvironment```. Many thanks! I'll edit and accept your answer.

Comment: Oops, has to be `\renewenvironment` of course. Glad it worked!

Comment: I edited your answer, but my edit will apparently not be visible to other people until it has been "approved by trusted community members".